# Gatsby Js redirects all pages to index page when the page is opened directly

Tags: gatsby, aws-amplify

I have a website in Gatsby Js. I have deployed it to AWS Amplify.

When I try to open a page directly, say /pricing, it is redirecting to the home page. I am able to open the page when I click on any  tag linking to that page.

Following is my build settings for AWS Amplify:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm install -g gatsby-cli
        - npm install
    build:
      commands:
        - gatsby build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: public
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Any clue where the issue can be?

Comment: Are you creating the pages with trailing slash?

Comment: https://www.mangochip.com/privacy If I open it directly it will redirect to home. If I go through link in footer it works properly.

Comment: It seems related to some AWS configuration rather than Gatsby but without seeing some implementation code I can be sure

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It is actually an AWS Amplify issue. It was redirecting all the traffic to index.html. I removed the rule and it is working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who may face the same issue. It has been fixed by double-checking AWS Amplify redirection rules.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? :)

Comment: Each case should be handled specifically. However, the resolution, in this case, was checking the AWS Amplify dashboard, in the rules section, to remove the rule that redirects all the traffic to `/index.html`